# How to access mnesia in remote server

Tags: database, erlang, mnesia, cowboy

I have an application built on Erlang/cowboy, the database is mnesia. The node name is webserver@127.0.0.1.

Since there is no GUI in remote server, I want to use local observer to access to the remote mnesia.

I tried many times, but still failed. Can anyone help me out? (Assume the IP of remote server is 10.123.45.67)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remote Erlang node name should be `webserver@10.123.45.67` instead of `webserver@127.0.0.1`.

Also you need to set the same **cookie** for both nodes as well as the same node **naming convention**. By naming convention I mean short name (`-sname` flag) or long name (`-name` flag), becuase a node with a long node name cannot communicate with a node with a short node name.

---

Note that if your real remote IP is not in a trusted network, it is not good practice to do it in case of security.

Comment: Still doesn't work, is there any special port I need open in remote server?

Comment: @ZhenguoYang Using `inet_dist_listen_min` and `inet_dist_listen_max` you can determine the port range which TCP ports of distributed Erlang uses to communicate through. So you need to make them accessible from outside. Check [this page](http://erlang.org/faq/how_do_i.html#idp32876368) for further explanation.

Comment: Works by adding inet_dist_listen_min and inet_dist_listen_max